# Can a let become a stroke after a 360° turn?

Tags: rules, squash

It is well known that if a player turns 360 degrees to hit the ball at the back wall then they may call a let for safety reasons, or play on and risk a stroke against them if they hit the opponent.

If they call a let and the opponent is directly between them and the front wall is a stroke awarded, or is it always only a let?